# Custom post type taxonomy image and link

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I currently have this menu (figure 1)

[image: figure 1]

When I click onto 'external products', I get a list of all the categories inside this, as figure 2 shows.
[image: figure 2]

What I am trying to do, is display all of the categories INSIDE external products. Which I do have working, with the following code:

```
      <div class="row">
   <?php
   $terms = get_terms('ExternalProducts');
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-6'>";

        $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'ExternalProducts','term'=>$term->slug);
        $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        $article_count = $myquery->post_count;
        echo "<h4 id=\"".$term->slug."\">";
        echo $term->name;
        echo "</h3>";
        echo "<p>";
        echo $term->description;     
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
  }
  ?>
```

My question(s) are:

1. How do I add an image to the CATEGORY, and display this along with the title and description?
2. How do I add a link from each category, to display all the posts inside this category.

If anyone can fix this, your AMAZING.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who needs the answer, I found this:

http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/

It worked a treat, simply follow the instructions!